# Is it possible to call the id or onclick of an asp radio button in javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, fabricjs

I have a customize order page form which has a ASP dropdownlists, asp textbox, asp radiobuttons, and ASP buttons BUT I also have a canvas that is mainly created using fabricjs One of the requirement is to send the data in the database which requires server side.

In radiobutton, what I need is once I selected for example Circle in shape an image circle will pop up in the canvas. But I am using asp radiobutton to store the data. Can anyone teach me how to call the id of the radiobutton and its format also the javascript?

[Shape Radiobuttons(Server Side)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAvXj.png)
[Canvas(Javascript)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UqqOu.png)

## ASP Radiobutton

```
   <asp:RadioButton ID="rbtnCircle" Text="Circle"  runat="server" GroupName="rbtnShapeList"/>
```

## script

```
fabric.Image.fromURL('image/rectangle.png', function(myImg) {
 canvas.add(myImg); 
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A RadioButtonList creates a html table with the RadioButtons inside. So you need to find the input controls by ID of the table (the Client ID of the RadioButtonList)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#<%= rbtnlistShape.ClientID %> input[type="radio"]').click(function () {
        alert($(this).prop("id"));
    });
</script>
```